# How to stretch width of a div within its container using sass?

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to build a responsive grid layout similar to bootstrap using sass.

```
@mixin responsive-breakpoint($var)
  &-#{$var}
    display: block
    width: 100%

  @for $i from 1 to 13
    &-#{$var}
      &-#{$i}
        @include column($i)

@mixin column($i)
  max-width: calc((100vw/12) * #{$i})

.col
  width: 100%
  float: left
  display: block
  @for $i from 1 to 13
    &-#{$i}
      @include column($i)
  @media (min-width: $sm)
    @include responsive-breakpoint(sm)
  @media (min-width: $md)
    @include responsive-breakpoint(md)
  @media (min-width: $lg)
    @include responsive-breakpoint(xl)
  @media (min-width: $xl)
    @include responsive-breakpoint(lg)
```

This is my sass code to generate conventional bootstrap responsive grid layout. What issue I'm experiencing here is, when I use `col-3` and `col` for two siblings, second sibling should stretch itself along the rest of width of the container as per bootstrap library, instead the second sibling stretches itself to the full width of the container. Can anyone find where I'm going wrong here? Or even this is the correct approach for a responsive grid layout. Today is my 3rd day with sass, so can anyone sort out this issue?

Comment: You might read into the [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) property.

Comment: Gosh! Forgot to add that flex property! It saved me!